# Using xcopy and del using SQL Server Agent Service Account

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

I am trying to use SQL Server Agent to perform some copy and delete actions on my backup files. I have created a Job as below:

[image: Job Step Properties]

Problem is when this job runs, it encounters an error. I believe it is due to SQL Server Agent Service Account not having sufficient privileges to perform xcopy and del commands. How do I resolve this?

Do I have to create a Credential then a Proxy? How do I do this?

**Update:**
I discovered this job failure has nothing to do with insufficient privileges. It is because I cannot refer to the destination network drive using the mapped drive. I have to spell out the entire network drive and place it in quotes, e.g., "`\\mynetworkdrive\folder name"`

Comment: You require to create a proxy which has appropriate access to that folder and you need to use that proxy in the "Run as"

Comment: You need to use a UNC of the form `\\Server\share\path`. You _also_ need to post the actual error in future as that would have helped. Have you solved your issue?

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Yes, I solved my issue and placed the solution in the "Update" section of my original post.

Comment: It does have _something_ to do with privileges... or users to be exact. The use that the agent runs under doesn't have that drive mapped.